# If $A$ is uncountable, then $f$ is constant function (true /false)

Tags: complex-analysis

Let  $f$ be  an entire function. Consider  $A=\{z \in \mathbb C\ |\  f^{n}(z)=0 \}$  for some  positive integer $n$. Then

1. If $A= \mathbb C$, then $f$ is  a  polynomial
2. If $A =\mathbb C$, then $f$ is  a constant polynomial
3. If $A$ is uncountable, then  $f$ is  a polynomial
4. If $A$ is uncountable, then  $f$ is  a constant function

**My attempt**:  I take  the zero function,  so option 2 and 4 are correct. Is it correct or not? Please tell me. I need only verification not an answer. If you have  time  then solution would be also fine.

Comment: pliz help me  i need only confirmation

Comment: help me  bachoa,,,bachao

Comment: You can't just take some function. A statement might be true for that function but not for other functions.

Comment: I don't understand your question, if you need "just a verification"  the zero function satisfies all conditions, since $0$ is a polynomial, but that doesn't mean that your conditions are true

Comment: You are being asked if $f$ has to be the way it is stated.  $2$ is false because  $f(z)=z+1$ has $f''(z)=0$ for all of $\Bbb C$ and is not a constant polynomial.  For 1 you need to show that every function that satisfies this is a polynomial.  My example shows 4 is false as well.  3 is a weakening of 1.  The question is whether an uncountable set is strong enough.

Comment: 2 and 4 are false, since every polynomial is entire.

Comment: @RossMillikan. Are you sure that $f^n$ refers to the $n$:th derivative of $f$? I thought that it was $\underbrace{f \circ \cdots \circ f}_{n \text{ "factors"}}$.

Comment: @md2perpe:  Not certain, but I believe it to be so.  I was also worried it might be the $n^{th}$ power of $f$.  I think the question makes sense with derivatives but not the other two.  Certainly with derivatives we have that polynomials satisfy the requirement and the first couple pieces are supposed to be easy.

Comment: Is n the same for all z, or is there an n (possibly different) for each z?